# Linux PCIe Driver: What to use for private data structure?

Tags: linux, driver, pci-e

I'm creating my first PCIe driver for Linux and have a question regarding which structure to use for the `pci_set_drvdata()` function.

The PCIe hardware is built in house and we will be using DMA to send data to and from the device. It is not a sound card or any other subsystem which needs to be plugged into the kernel.

When I look at examples there seems to be a specific `struct` to fill in and then send to `pci_set_drvdata()`.

What do I fill in for this case? Do I simply ignore this and send in a blank structure? The line I am referring to in any PCIe driver is:

```
struct structure_in_question *my_struct;
my_struct = kzalloc( sizeof(*my_struct), GFP_KERNEL) );
```

This is usually found in the `probe()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That function is used for associating with the device private data that cannot be supplied any other way. If there is no such data then the function should simply not be used.

Comment: So this is only for the driver itself for book keeping and no information is sent to the PCIe board or up to user-space?

Comment: @user2205930:  Correct.

Answer (score 0):

It is a convenient way for example to save a pointer to a local dynamically allocated device context in the device probe callback and then retrieve it back with pci_get_drvdata in the device remove callback and do a proper cleanup of the context.